Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in /home/hexamark/public_html/things/dcb/base.php on line 7
Hello I´m trying doing to verify the session in a PHP code, in the root files the error Session cannot be started after headers is not shown but in no this root file this session start doesnt work, I think that where the files are located isn't a problem because I have another files that the session start work fine. Also I tried changing PHP version from 8.1 to 8.0 because I red that this would be a solution but it doesnt work. The session_start() is on the second line of the file after the <?php.
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];

Solve the problem of Warning: session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in /home/hexamark/public_html/things/dcb/base.php

Possibly already answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php/8028987#8028987

This is a classic "Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent"
This issue occurs when you try to start a session after some output has already been sent to the browser. In PHP, the session_start function sends an HTTP header to the browser to set the session cookie. If any output has already been sent, PHP can't modify the headers anymore.
Here few things you can try:
Check for any output before session_start(): Make sure there is no whitespace, HTML, or any other output before the <?php opening tag.
check for any included files that are sending output.
Use putout buffering: you can try using output buffering to delay the output until the end of the script.
Here is the sample code:
<?php
    ob_start();
?>

You can find a similar issue here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/headers-already-sent-and-session-error/389959
